# Bold author if source is an article

Tags: biblatex, formatting, conditionals, bold

i got some articles i cite in my thesis. The author should be bold in the bibliography but i dont know how. I tried to use `\textbf` in the bibtex file but then the format isn't correct anymore. Would be nice if someone can help me.

i already got this to define the entries. just copied and pasted it.

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro*{author/editor+others/translator+others}{%
\mkbibbold{% ADDED
  \ifboolexpr{
test \ifuseauthor
and
not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
}
{\usebibmacro{author}}
{\ifboolexpr{
   test \ifuseeditor
   and
   not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
 }
   {\usebibmacro{editor+others}}
   {\usebibmacro{translator+others}}}}
}% ADDED

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\printlist{location}%
\iflistundef{publisher}
{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
%%    {\setunit*{addcolon\space}}% DELETED
{\setunit*{~:\space}}% ADDED
\printlist{publisher}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{date}%
\newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
%%    {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}% DELETED
    {\mkbibordedition{#1}\bibstring{edition}}% ADDED
    {#1\isdot}}
```

Comment: which bibtex style do you use?

Comment: \usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=alphabetic, bibstyle=alphabetic,  sorting=nyt, abbreviate=false]{biblatex}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test \ifuseauthor and not test {\ifnameundef{author}}}
    {\ifentrytype{article}{%
      \def\mkbibnamelast##1{\textbf{\textsc{##1}}}% 
      \def\mkbibnameprefix##1{\textbf{\textsc{##1}}}% 
      \def\mkbibnamefirst##1{\textbf{\textsc{##1}}}}{}%
     \printnames{author}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}{}{\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
    {}}
```

[image]

Comment: works fine, now the author just has to be in small caps then its perfect thx

Comment: See my edited answer ...

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the `first-last` name format (which is used by the `alphabetic` bibstyle) to include a test for the `article` entry type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
    \mkbibbold{%
      \iffirstinits
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
      \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
    }%
  }{%
    \iffirstinits
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  hyphenation = {english},
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
@book{Kop04,
  hyphenation = {ngerman},
  author = {Kopka, Helmut and Daly, Patrick W.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Guide to \LaTeX},
  edition = {4},
  location = {Boston},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it changes nothing but i dont know if its in conflict with this i copied and pasted to define the biliography entries

Comment: @Cheetah If my example works for you as-is, you must be doing something differently in your actual document.