# Authors typeset in bold in the reference list using bibtex

Tags: biblatex

There were some questions about this topic on the site yet, for example:

- [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex?lq=1)
- [Make specific author bold using biblatex without consistent author formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160132/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex-without-consistent-author-formatting?lq=1)
- [Bold author if source is an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61396/bold-author-if-source-is-an-article?rq=1)

The answer by @Audrey following first link is most elaborated.

**My question:** the @Audreu solution works fine with no applied style of *ieee* style but fails when I try with APA style:

```
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

Any suggestions or pointers how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution myself. I created the `biber.conf` file with the following rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" bmap_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_source="AUTHOR"
                map_match="Surname, Name"
                map_replace="\\textbf{Surname, N.}"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

You save `biber.conf` file in the same location as `*.tex` file and compile `*.tex` file as usually.