How do I make my name appear bold in reference list?
I am wrting a report, using biblatex, and I would like my name to appear in bold every time it appears at the end in the list of references, wherever it appears (first position or not). How to do it?
This is my preamble:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm, right=2.0cm, bottom=1.9cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=black,
citecolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk, amsmath, lineno, setspace, hyperref, graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=false,
  uniquelist=false,
  natbib=true, 
  style=apa,
  doi=true,
  url=false, 
  defernumbers=true,
  maxbibnames=50, 
  maxcitenames=1,
]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

%  A lot of text, citing things with \citep{Entry} and \citet{Entry}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}

EDIT: I found this partial solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194307/145851
One must enter a biber.conf file with the text to be replaced. Just had to make sure that always my name in the .bib list matches (e.g. Doe, J. is different from Doe, John). HOWEVER; this also makes the name bold in the middle of the text when you cite them (Doe, J. 2020). I don't want this to happen in the middle of the text, but only in the end in the references. How to constrain this behavior to the reference list?

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/?
